# How to align two lists according to an arbitrary criterion?

Tags: python

lets say I have two lists of persons, `persons_a` and `persons_b`. And I want to try to match each person in list `persons_a` with a person in `persons_b` according to an arbitrary attribute, for example `person.age`, `person.town_from` or so.

How could I do that in Python in a most efficient way?
Do I just do a for-loop?

```
criteria = lambda a, b: a.age == b.age

result = []
for a in persons_a:
    for b in persons_b:
        if critera(a, b):
           result.add(a)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
criteria = lambda a, b: a.age == b.age
cross = itertools.product( persons_a, persons_b )
result = ( a for a, b in cross if criteria( a, b ) )
```

This is more Pythonic and easier to read. The `itertools` is just a way to do the same nested for loops so it is not any more efficient just easier to read code.

Since you have to loop through each combinations you won't be able to get better than what you have of `O( n^2 )`, so unless you can short circuit the loop or come up with a single pass through both lists for a greedy algorithm then the above and your's are optimal solutions. If you have semi-structured data, in that there is say equal length lists that are also sorted then you may be able to speed up your code by being able to get through the list in a single pass, but if you do not have any kind of structure like this then you will have to stick with your `O( n^2 )` algorithm.

Comment: I would change the result into a generator, especially because it could be lengthy.

Comment: That is very true will change.

Answer (score 3):

Using nested for loops, as in the question and some previous answers, gives an O(m*n) algorithm, where m, n are the sizes of lists *a* and *b*.  (Or, O(n^2) if the lists are of the same size.)  To get an O(n) or O(n log n) algorithm, you could (1) use a set or dictionary data structure that supports O(1) or O(log n) membership lookups or could (2) sort *a* and/or *b* into order by the criterion element, to allow O(1) or O(log n) match testing.  See following example code, which uses two sorts that take O(n log n) time, followed by an O(n) comparison pass that identifies matching pairs, for overall time of O(n log n).

```
import collections
iTuple = collections.namedtuple('item',['data','age'])
p_a, p_b, n, p = [], [], 15, 19

for i in range(n):
   p_a.append(iTuple(i, ( 7*i)%p))
   p_b.append(iTuple(i, (11*i)%p))

sa = sorted(p_a, key=lambda x: x.age)
sb = sorted(p_b, key=lambda x: x.age)
#print ('sa: ', sa, '\n\nsb: ',sb, '\n')

ia, ib, result = 0, 0, []
while ia < n > ib:
   #print (ia, ib)
   if sa[ia].age == sb[ib].age:
      result.append([sa[ia], sb[ib]])
      print ('Match:', sa[ia], '\t', sb[ib],'\tat',ia,ib)
      ia, ib = ia+1, ib+1
   elif sa[ia].age  < sb[ib].age: ia += 1
   elif sa[ia].age >  sb[ib].age: ib += 1

#print ('Result:', result)
```

Here is the output from the above program.

```
Match: item(data=0, age=0)   item(data=0, age=0)    at 0 0
Match: item(data=11, age=1)  item(data=7, age=1)    at 1 1
Match: item(data=3, age=2)   item(data=14, age=2)   at 2 2
Match: item(data=14, age=3)  item(data=2, age=3)    at 3 3
Match: item(data=6, age=4)   item(data=9, age=4)    at 4 4
Match: item(data=9, age=6)   item(data=4, age=6)    at 5 5
Match: item(data=1, age=7)   item(data=11, age=7)   at 6 6
Match: item(data=4, age=9)   item(data=6, age=9)    at 8 7
Match: item(data=7, age=11)  item(data=1, age=11)   at 9 9
Match: item(data=2, age=14)  item(data=3, age=14)   at 11 11
Match: item(data=13, age=15) item(data=10, age=15)  at 12 12
Match: item(data=8, age=18)  item(data=12, age=18)  at 14 14
```

Answer (score 3):

By referring to a dictionary approach did you mean something like the following ?.

```
class Store() :

    def __init__(self,types):
        self.a = {}
        for i in types : self.a[i]={}

    def addToStore(self,item) : # item is a dictionary
        for key in item.keys() :
            if key in self.a :
                self.a[key][item[key]] =   self.a[key].setdefault(item[key],[])+[item]

    def printtype(self,atype) :
        print atype
        for i in self.a[atype] : print self.a[atype][i]

if __name__=="__main__" :
    persons= Store(["age","place"])
    persons.addToStore({"name" : "Smith" , "place" : "Bury" , "age" : 32 })
    persons.addToStore({"name" : "Jones" , "place" : "Bolton" , "age" : 35 })
    persons.addToStore({"name" : "Swift" , "place" : "Radcliffe" , "age" : 32 })
    persons.addToStore({"name" : "Issac" , "place" : "Rochdale" , "age" : 32 })
    persons.addToStore({"name" : "Phillips" , "place" : "Bolton" , "age" : 26 })
    persons.addToStore({"name" : "Smith" , "place" : "Bury" , "age" : 41 })
    persons.addToStore({"name" : "Smith" , "place" : "Ramsbottom" , "age" : 25 })
    persons.addToStore({"name" : "Wilson" , "place" : "Bolton" , "age" : 26 })
    persons.addToStore({"name" : "Jones" , "place" : "Heywood" , "age" : 72 })
    persons.printtype("age")
    persons.printtype("place")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = [a for a in persons_a for b in persons_b if critera(a, b)]
```

is your loop in [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) form.

Depending on what you plan to do with the result, you could as well use a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html?highlight=generator%20expression#generator-expressions) which looks nearly the same:

```
result = (a for a in persons_a for b in persons_b if critera(a, b))
```

The difference is that it doesn't occupy memory. Instead, it yields the values at the time they are asked for, just like with `yield` in a generator function.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are able to sort the persons according to that custom criterion:

Use [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to build a dictionary of one list (should be `O(n log n` for the sorting), then find the (exact) matches for the other pretty efficient (`O(m)`, that is constant for each of the persons in the other list.).

---

Here's an illustrative implementation:

```
import random
import collections
import itertools
iTuple = collections.namedtuple('Person', ['town', 'age'])

# make up data
random.seed(1)
def random_person():
    age = random.randrange(19,49)
    town = random.choice("Edinburgh Glasgow Aberdeen".split())
    return iTuple(town, age)
n_f, n_m = 15, 20
females = [random_person() for x in xrange(n_f)]
males = [random_person() for x in xrange(n_m)]

# group by criterion of interest: age, town
by_age, by_town = lambda x: x.age, lambda x: x.town
males_by_age = dict((age, list(group)) for age, group in itertools.groupby(
        sorted(males, key=by_age), key=by_age))
males_by_town = dict((age, list(group)) for age, group in itertools.groupby(
        sorted(males, key=by_town), key=by_town))
```

Then you can query this dictionary to get the list of matches:

```
# assign random matches according to grouping variable (if available)
print "matches by age:"
for person in females:
    candidates = males_by_age.get(person.age)
    if candidates:
        print person, random.choice(candidates)
    else:
        print person, "no match found"

print "matches by town:"
for person in females:
    candidates = males_by_town.get(person.town)
    if candidates:
        print person, random.choice(candidates)
    else:
        print person, "no match found"
```

The output is similar to:

```
matches by age:
Person(town='Aberdeen', age=23) no match found
Person(town='Edinburgh', age=41) no match found
Person(town='Glasgow', age=33) no match found
Person(town='Aberdeen', age=38) Person(town='Edinburgh', age=38)
Person(town='Edinburgh', age=21) no match found
Person(town='Glasgow', age=44) Person(town='Glasgow', age=44)
Person(town='Edinburgh', age=41) no match found
Person(town='Aberdeen', age=32) no match found
Person(town='Aberdeen', age=25) Person(town='Edinburgh', age=25)
Person(town='Edinburgh', age=46) no match found
Person(town='Glasgow', age=19) no match found
Person(town='Glasgow', age=47) Person(town='Glasgow', age=47)
Person(town='Glasgow', age=25) Person(town='Glasgow', age=25)
Person(town='Edinburgh', age=19) no match found
Person(town='Glasgow', age=32) no match found
matches by town:
Person(town='Aberdeen', age=23) Person(town='Aberdeen', age=45)
Person(town='Edinburgh', age=41) Person(town='Edinburgh', age=27)
Person(town='Glasgow', age=33) Person(town='Glasgow', age=44)
Person(town='Aberdeen', age=38) Person(town='Aberdeen', age=45)
Person(town='Edinburgh', age=21) Person(town='Edinburgh', age=20)
Person(town='Glasgow', age=44) Person(town='Glasgow', age=24)
Person(town='Edinburgh', age=41) Person(town='Edinburgh', age=38)
Person(town='Aberdeen', age=32) Person(town='Aberdeen', age=34)
Person(town='Aberdeen', age=25) Person(town='Aberdeen', age=40)
Person(town='Edinburgh', age=46) Person(town='Edinburgh', age=38)
Person(town='Glasgow', age=19) Person(town='Glasgow', age=34)
Person(town='Glasgow', age=47) Person(town='Glasgow', age=42)
Person(town='Glasgow', age=25) Person(town='Glasgow', age=34)
Person(town='Edinburgh', age=19) Person(town='Edinburgh', age=27)
Person(town='Glasgow', age=32) Person(town='Glasgow', age=34)
```